# Keep Imputed Values Consistent Within Participant

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I've run a multiple imputation with mice for data in long format (8 observations per subject) after setting the subject_id to 0 to exclude it as a predictor.

The only issue is that when subject_id is not included as a predictor then sometimes a missing variable like "gender" can be imputed differently for time 1 vs time 2, etc. Does anyone know how to specify that how these sort of variables should stay consistent across timepoints?

```
#Make imputation not use subject id
ini <- mice::mice(imputation_data_long, maxit=0) #Dry run without iterations to get the prediction matrix
pred1 <- ini$predictorMatrix # this is your predictor matrix
pred1[,'subject_id'] <- 0 # set all id column values to zero to exclude it as a predictor
#Run Imputation
all_imputations <- mice::mice(imputation_data_long, maxit= 5, m = 5, seed = 123, pred = pred1)
```